# Login a prestashop user from external web application

Tags: c#, prestashop

I would login Prestashop user from an external web application (developed in c#) and then redirect him to my Prestashop as a connected user.

My approach consist in a POST HTTP call to the ‘authentication’ controller of the Prestashop with this parameters and theirs respective values:
-   email > afolin@scriba.fr
-   passwd > hash in MD5
-   back > my-account
-   SubmitLogin > true

The HTTP response is OK, but when it redirect to the Prestashop, the user isn’t connected.
I understand that a cookie is necessary to auto connect, but I don’t know how to get it.

So I have two questions:
-   Is my approach correct ?
-   How to implement the cookie in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the authentication should be saved in the cookie, this mean that the user should create the session in the browser, when you make a POST request from your server the session is saved for your server NOT for the user, in other words, you can't create a remote session for a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach isn't correct because you can't get a cookie within it. The best way to achieve your goal is to create a module which will handle the necessary part for you. It should contain a front controller to which you'll pass the username and password instead of the authentication controller and then handle the authentication for you. [Here you can read more about modules](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/)